# Interaction of Angular components and CSS+DOM

Tags: angular, dom

I'm new to Angular and am having trouble figuring out how to refactor duplicate code into components, without the extra tags inserted by components causing problems with my CSS and DOM structure.

For example, if I have a Bootstrap-styled `<dl>` list:

```
  <dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-4">Obi-Wan</dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-8">hermit</dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-4">Luke</dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-8">farmer</dd>
  </dl>
```

I want to remove the duplicate styles, and I want to add additional functionality (like tooltips) without repeating that for each tag, so I create and use a definition component:

```
  <dl class="row">
    <app-definition caption="Obi-Wan">hermit</app-definition>
    <app-definition caption="Luke">farmer</app-definition>
  </dl>
```

But now `<app-definition>` gets its own node in the DOM tree, so styling and `<dl>` semantics are messed up.

[Here's a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QOY3jFI259Dvhw01fuMF?p=preview) demonstrating this. (For my app, some of the dt+dd nodes may have different attributes, and some of the dd nodes may have more complicated contents, so stuffing everything in an array then using `ngFor` would be a poor fit.)

Any suggestions for how I can refactor this to reduce duplication without it causing problems for my DOM? I'm used to React, where calling a component can substitute what that component returns, instead of necessarily inserting a new tag.

Comment: You need to follow this thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22208

Comment: @yurzui - Yes, that sounds like what I'm wanting. Thanks.